# python name '_mysql' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, django

I build a virtual environment with python 3.7.10,
by installing mysql and mysqlclient
It is mysql 8.0.28, mysqlclient 2.1.0.

When running python manage.py migrate
It comes out like this:

```
(test) ➜  backend git:(main) python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

When I try to reinstall it, it says it's already installed.
I think python can't find the mysql path.
I looked through many questions, but couldn't solve my problem.
Since I started python for the first time, I can't find the cause.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Where do I start to catch the problem?

Comment: Try destroying and recreating the `test` environment (reinstalling dependencies).

Answer (score 13):

This is because the version of the mysql C library(_mysql*.so) in MySQLdb is not compatible with the Python version. Activating virtual environment and try this:

```
 pip uninstall mysqlclient
 pip install mysqlclient --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of days ago I had the same issue. Make sure `mysqlclient` is installed and then install `pip install PyMySQL` , Now use the following lines of code in settings.py:

**#in settings.py**

```
import pymysql  
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

this works for me.

Comment: You wouldn't need to have `mysqlclient` (a binary mysql client) installed if you are going to use `PyMySQL` (the pure-Python mysql client) anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot, @AKX , I was looking for the reason till now :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your python version path matches the homebrew python's path:

```
which python3

/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3
```

Then install mysqlclient, once you create a virtual env with the above python3:
pip install mysqlclient